# Set default team timezone in Slack

Tags: slack, time-zone

People are signing into our newly created Slack team with the timezone `UTC-7` but we are in `UTC+10`. I can find where people can manually change their timezone but I am trying to work out how I can either change it for them or simply set our team so all new people from here are by default in UTC+10. Is this achievable and where do I find it?

Comment: Thanks to the fellow who took it upon himself to edit my question and change my fine UK English to US English while introducing grammatical issues. Thanks to the other editor for correcting those edits. Shame the same gusto didn't go into the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, sadly, is it cannot be done, at least not at this time of writing.

I wrote to Slack support directly who advise this is not possible. I then asked if they could at least add support so people's default timezone is picked up from their device. They advised this is a commonly requested feature and is on their roadmap.

So, I am answering my own question as the official answer is this is not possible at this time - disappointing but true.